# Service - show keyboard AND full navigation bar at once

Tags: android, service, android-softkeyboard

From my service (a service for a sidebar app), I show the keyboard like following:

```
public static void showKeyboard(Context parent)
{
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)parent.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(
            InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,
            InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
}
```

The problem is, on devices without hardware buttons (for back, menu, recents), the navigation bar turns black and does not show the back, menu and recents buttons anymore, when the keyboard is shown.

How can I avoid this?